# libgtk1.2 deb install fails

Tags: apt, dpkg, dependencies

I'm trying to install libgtk1.2, but the install fails.

```
sudo dpkg -i libgtk1.2_1.2.10-18.1build2_i386.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package libgtk1.2:i386.
(Reading database ... 226813 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libgtk1.2_1.2.10-18.1build2_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libgtk1.2:i386 (1.2.10-18.1build2) ...
dpkg: libgtk1.2:i386: dependency problems, but configuring anyway as you requested:
 libgtk1.2:i386 depends on libgtk1.2-common (>= 1.2.10-18.1build2).

Setting up libgtk1.2:i386 (1.2.10-18.1build2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
```

It fails on the libgtk1.2-common dependency, but I already have that installed.

```
apt list --installed | grep libgtk
...
libgtk1.2/now 1.2.10-18.1build2 i386 [installed,local]
libgtk1.2-common/now 1.2.10-18.1build2 all [installed,local]
...
```

The libgtk1.2-common was installed as a deb. The dependency for libgtk1.2 is looking for 1.2.10-18.1build2, that matches the libgtk1.2-common I have installed.

Why is libgtk1.2 failing to see the dependency? How can I fix this?

Note, I understand libgtk1.2 is old, but I require it for an older application. Another thing to note is that the application I use works if I leave the broken libgtk1.2 installed, but that means I can no longer install any package. Any new software requires me to run 'sudo apt-get -f install' which will remove the libgtk1.2 (since it is broken).

*edit*: My guess is because the common is an 'all' package, the i386 libgtk1.2 isn't seeing it as installed. Not sure how to proceed though and get this working.

*edit*: Here is the requested command output.

```
sudo apt-get -f installReading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libxi6:i386
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libgtk1.2:i386
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 11 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 1,876 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 226826 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libgtk1.2:i386 (1.2.10-18.1build2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
```

Comment: What happens if you run `sudo apt-get install -f`? What packages does it install?

Comment: @Zacharee1 I edited the main post with the command output. It does not install anything, only removes the libgtk1.2 package as that install failed and is marked as broken due to the dependency.

Comment: See if you can do an `upgrade` and `dist-upgrade`.

Comment: @Zacharee1 No dice. There were a couple packages that had an update, but nothing to do with libgtk. libgtk still won't see the libgtk-common dependency. I ended up trying to install the libgtk-3:i386 package and creating a symlink to see if that word work for the app I need, but no dice. I really do need libgtk1.2.

Comment: @Zacharee1 FYI I posted an answer below (can't mark as answered for 2 days). I was able to find out how to modify the .deb to allow libgtk1.2 to see libgtk1.2-common.

Comment: Nice work. This could come in handy for others in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution**

```
dpkg-deb -x libgtk1.2-common_1.2.10-18.1build2_all.deb tmp
dpkg-deb --control libgtk1.2-common_1.2.10-18.1build2_all.deb tmp/DEBIAN
vi tmp/DEBIAN/control
--add the following line >> Multi-Arch: foreign
dpkg -b tmp libgtk1.2-common_1.2.10-18.1build2_all_new.deb
sudo dpkg -i libgtk1.2-common_1.2.10-18.1build2_all_new.deb
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo dpkg -i libgtk1.2_1.2.10-18.1build2_i386.deb
sudo apt-get -f install
```

[Source](https://geekwentfreak-raviteja.rhcloud.com/blog/2012/10/10/modify-dependencies-addremove-files-of-debian-deb-package/)

By modifying the deb to support foreign Multi-Arch it allowed libgtk1.2 to see libgtk1.2-common. libgtk1.2 was i386 and I am on x86_64. Without the modification, libgtk1.2 couldn't see  libgtk1.2-common.